# facebook user validation

Tags: iphone, validation, facebook

I have an Iphone app. I am using facebook connect when for user authentication.
I am sending score and fbuser Id to my web server. How can I validation this user valid or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your user login to FB using your app, then you have his valid fb id.

If you get users' friends using FBConnect, then you also have theirs fb id. Then they are also valid, so what are you scared of when all the FB ID is returned from FB API?

Comment: anyone can send another userId with zero score in my application user list.

Comment: You mean you allow people to input their user id manually? If user cannot touch the user id, all are from fb, how can anyone can send it?

Comment: no, there are two different platform : iphone, webservis. User use iphone for facebook connect  than user can send score to webservice. But some people can send userId and score with another application to webservice.

Comment: then you want to validate if the fb uid is a valid fb id or you want to check if the fb uid is coming from the correct person, not anyone who sends you a friend'fb uid?

Comment: If you want the first, then one of the easiest way is to call graph API: https://graph.facebook.com/ID . If the ID exists then some data will be returned

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue of game hacking. It's not possible to make a clientside score that can't be tampered with.

You can either:

- Try to thwart them by encrypting the score and FacebookId before it's sent to your webserver.
- Run the game on your webserver. The client only passes the players moves to the server.